# monomial basis conditioning

Tags: linear-algebra

In [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k68Mf8VAQz8&ab_channel=ENLASeminar) delivered by professor N. Trefethen it is stated that the condition number of a Vandermonde matrix of degree n verifies:
$$\kappa\sim(1+\sqrt{2})^{n}$$
It is based on [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01437212) by Gautschi. Unfortunately, I do not have access to that paper. How can I justify this approximation ?

Comment: That does not seem correct as you stated it; $\kappa$ should depend on the choice of nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gautschi's paper can be downloaded from [here.](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/wxg/selected_works/section_01/052.pdf) You may find [An elementary proof of the exponential conditioning of real Vandermonde matrices](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237836551_An_elementary_proof_of_the_exponential_conditioning_of_real_Vandermonde_matrices) more easily understandable. For real distinct nodes the condition number has the lower bound
$$\kappa\geq \sqrt{\frac{2}{n+1}}\bigl(1+\sqrt 2\bigr)^{n-1}.$$